# How to use a view controller as a side menu in Swift3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8, side-menu

I am trying to implement the side menu in my application programatically. So I have designed a view controller with half of its view as table view. The design as well as coding is done, now i wish to use this view controller as a Side Menu controller. My SideMenu Storyboard is:

[image]

Now my code looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class SideBarViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var menu: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var menuTableView: UITableView!
  var fieldImages = [UIImage]()
  var isFirstSectionHidden: Bool = true
  var isSecondSectionHidden: Bool = true
  var selectedIndex: Int = 0
  var menuTag: Int = 0
  var name = ""
  var email = ""
  var imageURL = ""
  var language = "English"

  var accountNames: [String] = ["My Subscriptions", "My Proposals","My Interests"]
  var languageNames: [String] = ["English", "Arabic", "Malayalam"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      selectedIndex = -1
      self.menu.isHidden = true
      menuTag = 0
     // self.profile()
      let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
      swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
      self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

      let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
      swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
      self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
      self.fieldImages.append(UIImage(named: "my_subscription_icon")!)
      self.fieldImages.append(UIImage(named: "my_proposal_icon")!)
      self.fieldImages.append(UIImage(named: "my_interest_icon")!)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
  func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
  if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
  switch swipeGesture.direction {
  case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
    menuAction()
  print("Swiped right")
  case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
    menuAction()
  print("Swiped left")
  default:
  break
  }
  }
  }
  func menuAction() {
    if menuTag == 0 {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.menu.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.menu.frame.size.width, height: self.menu.frame.size.height)
        self.menu.isHidden = false
        self.menuTag = 1
        self.menuTableView.reloadData()
      })
    }
    else {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.menu.frame = CGRect(x: -self.menu.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: self.menu.frame.size.width, height: self.menu.frame.size.height)
          self.menu.isHidden = true
        self.menuTag = 0
        self.menuTableView.reloadData()
      })
      selectedIndex = -1

    }
  }
  func profile() {
    if Utility.isConnectedToInternet {
      Utility.startActivityIdicator()
      VanpoolAPI.profile { (response) in
        Utility.stopActivityIndicator()
        if response == nil {
          Utility.showAlert(title: Constants.error, message: Constants.someThingWrong, delegate: self)
        } else {
          if response?.status == ResponseCode.success.code {
            self.name = (response?.name)!
            self.email = (response?.email)!
            self.imageURL = (response?.displayPictureUrl)!
          } else {
            Utility.showAlert(title:Constants.appName, message:response?.message?.key ?? "", delegate: self)
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      Utility.showAlert(title: Constants.appName, message: Constants.noNetwork, delegate: self)
    }
  }
  func logout() {
    if Utility.isConnectedToInternet {
      Utility.startActivityIdicator()
      VanpoolAPI.logout { (response) in
        Utility.stopActivityIndicator()
        if response == nil {
          Utility.showAlert(title: Constants.error, message: Constants.someThingWrong, delegate: self)
        } else {
          if response?.status == ResponseCode.success.code {
          } else {
            Utility.showAlert(title:Constants.appName, message:response?.message?.key ?? "", delegate: self)
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      Utility.showAlert(title: Constants.appName, message: Constants.noNetwork, delegate: self)
    }
  }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
extension SideBarViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return 11
  }
  // number of rows in table view
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
      return 1
    } else if selectedIndex == section {
      return 3
    } else {
      return 0
    }
}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:

  let cellProfile = (menuTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"profileCell", for: indexPath)as? MenuTableViewCell)!
   cellProfile.profile.layer.masksToBounds = false
   cellProfile.profile.layer.cornerRadius = cellProfile.profile.frame.height/2
   cellProfile.profile.clipsToBounds = true
   cellProfile.name.text = self.name
   cellProfile.email.text = self.email
   cell = cellProfile
    case 3:
  let cellAccount = (menuTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"accountCell", for: indexPath)as? MenuAccountTableViewCell)!
   cellAccount.title.text = accountNames[indexPath.row]
  cellAccount.icon.image = fieldImages[indexPath.row]
      cell = cellAccount
    case 5:
  let cellLanguage = (menuTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"languageCell", for: indexPath)as? MenuLanguageTableViewCell)!
  cellLanguage.languageLabel.text = languageNames[indexPath.row]
    cell = cellLanguage
    default:
      print("Something else")

    }
    return cell
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 5:
     let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MenuLanguageTableViewCell
     language = (currentCell?.languageLabel.text)!
     selectedIndex = -1
     isSecondSectionHidden = true
     menuTableView.reloadData()
    default:
      print("Something else")
    }
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
      return 180
    } else if indexPath.section == 3||indexPath.section == 5 {
      return 40
    }
    return 0
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
      return 0
    }
   return 50
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: menuTableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    let headerImage = UIImageView()
    headerImage.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: 12, height: 12)
    let headerLbl = UILabel()
    headerLbl.frame = CGRect(x: headerImage.frame.origin.x + headerImage.frame.size.width + 20, y: 10, width:menuTableView.frame.size.width - 40, height: 20)
    headerLbl.font = UIFont().robotoLight(withFontSize: 9)
    headerLbl.textColor = CustomColor.menuGrey.color
    let arrowImage = UIImageView()
    arrowImage.isHidden = true
    switch section {
    case 1:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "home_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "Home"
    case 2:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "my_Id_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "My ID"
    case 3:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "my_interest_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "My Account"
    arrowImage.isHidden = false
    if isFirstSectionHidden {
      arrowImage.frame = CGRect(x: menuTableView.frame.size.width - 30, y: 15, width: 3, height: 5)
      arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "side_arrow")
    } else {
       arrowImage.frame = CGRect(x: menuTableView.frame.size.width - 30, y: 15, width: 5, height: 3)
    arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "down_arrow")
      }
    case 4:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "my_profile_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "My Profile"
    case 5:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "language_icon")
    headerLbl.text = language
    arrowImage.isHidden = false
    if isSecondSectionHidden {
      arrowImage.frame = CGRect(x: menuTableView.frame.size.width - 30, y: 15, width: 3, height: 5)
      arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "side_arrow")
    } else {
      arrowImage.frame = CGRect(x: menuTableView.frame.size.width - 30, y: 15, width: 5, height: 3)
      arrowImage.image = UIImage(named: "down_arrow")
      }

    case 6:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "notification_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "Notifications"
    case 7:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "about_us_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "About Us"
    case 8:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "faq_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "FAQ"
    case 9:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "contact_us_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "Contact Us"
    case 10:
    headerImage.image = UIImage(named: "logout_icon")
    headerLbl.text = "Logout"
    default:
      print("Something else")

    }
      let headerClick = UIButton(type: .custom)
      headerClick.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.headerAction), for: .touchUpInside)
      headerClick.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: menuTableView.frame.size.width, height: 40)
      headerClick.tag = section
      headerClick.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    headerView.addSubview(arrowImage)
    headerView.addSubview(headerLbl)
    headerView.addSubview(headerImage)
    headerView.addSubview(headerClick)
    return headerView
  }
  func headerAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 3 {
      if isFirstSectionHidden  {
        selectedIndex = Int(sender.tag)
        isFirstSectionHidden = false
        isSecondSectionHidden  = true
      } else {
        selectedIndex = -1
        isFirstSectionHidden  = true

      }
    }else if sender.tag == 5 {
        if isSecondSectionHidden  {
          selectedIndex = Int(sender.tag)
          isSecondSectionHidden = false
          isFirstSectionHidden = true
        } else {
          selectedIndex = -1
          isSecondSectionHidden = true
        }
    } else {
    selectedIndex = -1
      isSecondSectionHidden = true
      isFirstSectionHidden = true
    }
     menuTableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Any idea how to do this view controller as my side view controller programatically. Note, i am trying to avoid the third party classes at the best.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDERN.gif]

Comment: What is the current situation? With above code what is the result?

Comment: current situation is very bad. With above code i am getting only the controller for side menu. No idea how to implement this.

Comment: Ok what I have understood is this scenario, you have a viewController A and viewController B , when you swipe right on viewController A, you want to show viewController B sliding from the left to right, am I right?

Comment: yes offcourse glad u understand :)

Comment: Yes i will surely look. But i would like to acheive the image like this as updated in the question

Comment: the menu should over the top of each and every view controller

Comment: @user1000 IT WOULD HAVE BEEN SO NICE OF YOU IF YOU IMPLEMENT IT ... :)

Comment: It might be pretty simple. Have a root view controller as a subclass the UITabbarViewController and hide the tab bar menu all the time. And add the side menu view controller as a child view controller and programmatically change the tab bar's selected index.

Answer (score 2):

Simple you can do is

Now

**1.** In Base View Controller add a container view. Add Side View Controller to container view via segue

**2.** Make Container view width 275 or as per requirement.

**3.** Add constraints to container view trailing (assuming side menu right side of view), top , bottom and constant width.

**4.** Now create outlet of trailing constraint in view and toggle its constant value -275 to hide and 0 to show.

P.S. I have sample project also https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByCC2aGldkpUVU0xUkd5bTRCNzQ