# hamburger menu / sidemenu appearance error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, constraints

After my login screen home view appears correctly but when I add a hamburger/side menu then after logging in the home view gets blank.

I have added a view into my home view for hamburger/side menu which is the cause of disappearing everything from home screen how to handle it.
I also have added proper constraints for subview.

[image: home view appearance along with hamburger/side menu]

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing? Where have you added the sideBar's View? The question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Try like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735883/5589073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a side menu bar with something of this sort:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sideMenu: UIView!
var sideMenuHiddenTransform: CGAffineTransform!
var sideMenuHidden = true
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sideMenuHiddenTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: -(sideMenu.bounds.width), y: 0)
    sideMenu.transform = sideMenuHiddenTransform
}

@IBAction func showHideMenu(_ sender: Any) {
    if sideMenuHidden{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.sideMenu.transform = .identity
        })
    }else{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.sideMenu.transform = self.sideMenuHiddenTransform
        })
    }
    sideMenuHidden = !sideMenuHidden
```

Layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try checking **Custom Code** for **side menu Drawer** , To Apply it Just Add a button in mainController and Add a Separate controller that will act as Side Drawer

For now I had used `notification observers` for Passing cell index from side menu to main controller , you can make use of `Protocols`

Link - https://github.com/RockinGarg/Slide-Menu-Drawer.git

**Code is fully customised using Pan Gesture i.e you can also make side View Draggable after Displaying or adding in main Subview**

Side menu Drawer UIViewController object

```
  private lazy var sideMenuVCObject: SideMenuVC =
{
    // Instantiate View Controller
    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuVC") as! SideMenuVC

    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.addChildViewController(viewController)
    return viewController
}()
```

**Screenshot**

[image]